# Hashing a point on cubic sphere

Tags: mathematics

Let's say I have a point on a potential cubic sphere inflated using this:

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(x, y, z) * 2f / gridSize - Vector3.one;
float x2 = v.x * v.x;
float y2 = v.y * v.y;
float z2 = v.z * v.z;
Vector3 s;
s.x = v.x * Mathf.Sqrt(1f - y2 / 2f - z2 / 2f + y2 * z2 / 3f);
s.y = v.y * Mathf.Sqrt(1f - x2 / 2f - z2 / 2f + x2 * z2 / 3f);
s.z = v.z * Mathf.Sqrt(1f - x2 / 2f - y2 / 2f + x2 * y2 / 3f);
normals[i] = s;
vertices[i] = normals[i] * radius;
```

from: [Cube Sphere | Unity C# Tutorial](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/cube-sphere/)

After finding the cube face the point belong to, how do I find which spatial hash it belong to, ie which grid cells for any given arbitrary division?